# T-SQL Cumulative Count Reset per Month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to count cumulative count in T-SQL. This can be done as:

```
WITH DATASET AS (SELECT '2014-01-28' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-29' AS [DATE], 5 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-30' AS [DATE], 15 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-31' AS [DATE], 4 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-01' AS [DATE], 7 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-02' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
)
, CTE AS (SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) ROWNUM
FROM DATASET
)
SELECT CTE1.[DATE]
,CTE1.[COUNT]
,SUM(CTE2.[COUNT]) AS CUM_CNT
FROM CTE CTE1
JOIN CTE CTE2 ON CTE2.ROWNUM <= CTE1.ROWNUM
GROUP BY CTE1.[DATE]
,CTE1.[COUNT]
```

That returns:

```
DATE        COUNT   CUM_CNT
2014-01-28      1        1
2014-01-29      5        6
2014-01-30     15       21
2014-01-31      4       25
2014-02-01      7       32
2014-02-02      1       33
```

But I want to reset the cumulative count per each month so the data returned should be:

```
DATE        COUNT   CUM_CNT
2014-01-28      1        1
2014-01-29      5        6
2014-01-30     15       21
2014-01-31      4       25
2014-02-01      7        7
2014-02-02      1        8
```

Is it possible to achieve this in T-SQL? How?

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: you could join only rows of the same month.

Comment: SQL Server 2014, .. I could but how to do it dynamically? The full data set contains data e.g. year 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2012+ you can use window version of `SUM` to calculate running totals. You just have to `PARTITION` by `YEAR([DATE]), MONTH([DATE])` to get the expected result:

```
WITH DATASET AS (
SELECT '2014-01-28' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-29' AS [DATE], 5 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-30' AS [DATE], 15 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-31' AS [DATE], 4 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-01' AS [DATE], 7 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-02' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
)
SELECT [DATE], [COUNT], 
       SUM([COUNT]) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR([DATE]), MONTH([DATE])
                          ORDER BY [DATE]) AS CUM_CNT
FROM DATASET
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6782/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '2014-01-28' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-29' AS [DATE], 5 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-30' AS [DATE], 15 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-01-31' AS [DATE], 4 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-01' AS [DATE], 7 AS [COUNT]
UNION
SELECT '2014-02-02' AS [DATE], 1 AS [COUNT]
)
Select C2.date,sum(c1.count) as COUNT, sum(distinct c2.count) AS CUML_COUNT from DATASET C1
JOIN DATASET C2 ON month(C1.date) = month(C2.date) and C1.Date <= C2.Date
group by C2.date
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of how this differs from the accepted answer, and why you prefer it?